# can I avoid a c++11 move when initializing an array?

Tags: c++, c++11

I used C++11 features to make my own smaller implementation of [StrCat](https://github.com/google/lmctfy/blob/master/strings/strcat.h), in part to try out C++11 variadic templates. (Also to avoid the annoyance of either depending on a new library just for something I can write in a few lines of code or copying the longer code into my own program, adding a note about its license, etc).

My implementation seems to work, but I wasn't able to do it without having a move constructor for StrCatPiece. That's troubling because I don't see how the default move constructor could be safe: if the original StrCatPiece's `piece_` refers to an address within `buf_`, the new StrCatPiece's `piece_` will also refer to an address within the original `buf_`, not the new `buf_`. I don't see any guarantee the original buffer will live until it's no longer referenced.

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) 5.2.1 20151010
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Without move constructor:

```
$ g++ -Wall -g --std=c++11 strcattest.cc -o strcattest
strcattest.cc: In instantiation of ‘std::__cxx11::string StrCat(Types ...) [with Types = {const char*, int}; std::__cxx11::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’:
strcattest.cc:54:33:   required from here
strcattest.cc:39:38: error: use of deleted function ‘StrCatPiece::StrCatPiece(const StrCatPiece&)’
   auto pieces = {StrCatPiece(args)...};
...
```

My custom move constructor is apparently elided by my compiler:

```
$ g++ -Wall -g --std=c++11 strcattest.cc -o strcattest
$ ./strcattest 
foo 26
```

but if I force it to run with my custom move constructor that calls `abort()`, the program crashes as expected:

```
$ g++ -Wall -g -fno-elide-constructors --std=c++11 strcattest.cc -o strcattest
$ ./strcattest
Aborted
```

If I instead have a default move constructor, it seems to work, but I'm suspicious...so in gdb I can confirm that the StringPiece points somewhere other than the current buffer:

```
(gdb) break 39
Breakpoint 1 at 0x401249: file strcattest.cc, line 39.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/slamb/strcattest 

Breakpoint 1, StrCat<char const*, int> () at strcattest.cc:39
39    size_t size = 0;
(gdb) print pieces
$1 = {_M_array = 0x7fffffffe9b0, _M_len = 2}
(gdb) print pieces._M_array
$2 = (std::initializer_list<StrCatPiece>::iterator) 0x7fffffffe9b0
(gdb) print pieces._M_array[1]
$3 = {piece_ = {ptr_ = 0x7fffffffe972 "26", length_ = 2, 
    static npos = <optimized out>}, 
  buf_ = "\006\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\360\350G\367\377\177\000\000\001\000\062\066"}
(gdb) print (void*)pieces._M_array[1].buf_
$4 = (void *) 0x7fffffffe9e8
(gdb) print (void*)pieces._M_array[1].buf_ + 20
$6 = (void *) 0x7fffffffe9fc
```

In particular, 0x7fffffffe972 is not in [0x7fffffffe9e8, 0x7fffffffe9fc)!

I could define a working copy constructor, but I'm wondering if there's a way to avoid the copy/move entirely.

Here's the code:

```
// Compile with: g++ -Wall --std=c++11 strcattest.cc -o strcattest
#include <re2/stringpiece.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <iostream>

class StrCatPiece {
 public:
  explicit StrCatPiece(uint64_t p);
  explicit StrCatPiece(re2::StringPiece p) : piece_(p) {}

  StrCatPiece(const StrCatPiece &) = delete;
  //StrCatPiece(StrCatPiece &&) { abort(); }
  StrCatPiece &operator=(const StrCatPiece &) = delete;

  const char *data() const { return piece_.data(); }
  size_t size() const { return piece_.size(); }

 private:
  re2::StringPiece piece_;
  char buf_[20];  // length of maximum uint64 (no terminator needed).
};

StrCatPiece::StrCatPiece(uint64_t p) {
  if (p == 0) {
    piece_ = "0";
  } else {
    size_t i = sizeof(buf_);
    while (p != 0) {
      buf_[--i] = '0' + (p % 10);
      p /= 10;
    }
    piece_.set(buf_ + i, sizeof(buf_) - i);
  }
}

template <typename... Types>
std::string StrCat(Types... args) {
  auto pieces = {StrCatPiece(args)...};
  size_t size = 0;
  for (const auto &p : pieces) {
    size += p.size();
  }
  std::string out;
  out.reserve(size);
  for (const auto &p : pieces) {
    out.append(p.data(), p.size());
  }
  return out;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  std::cout << StrCat("foo ", 26) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

---

Edit: adding a copy constructor of course does work:

```
StrCatPiece::StrCatPiece(const StrCatPiece &o) {
  const char* data = o.piece_.data();
  if (o.buf_ <= data && data < o.buf_ + sizeof(o.buf_)) {
    memcpy(buf_, data, o.piece_.size());
    piece_.set(buf_, o.piece_.size());
  } else {
    piece_ = o.piece_;
  }
}
```

Still curious if it is possible to entirely avoid moving or copying the StrCatPiece (always, not just as a compiler optimization), or if not, why not.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You can't move a static array. If you don't want a copy or move constructor, how do you intend to copy the class?

Comment: As a practical fix, use indices instead of pointers, and pass the buffer to the append operation.

Comment: what is a `re2::StringPiece` ?

Comment: Your options are going to be : (a) design your class so the implicitly-generated move constructor works correctly;  or (b) write your own move constructor.  (and probably move-assignment operator too).

Comment: @M.M re2::StringPiece is a pointer/length into a string that it doesnt own. https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/re2/stringpiece.h

Comment: @JamesRoot I'd prefer to not copy or move the class, instead constructing it in the right place. If that's not possible, I guess I'll copy it. The index that Alf mentioned seems possible, too, but I'd need to have data() and size() have two cases (index to local buf vs piece_ to remote string) instead of one.

Comment: [Wait for C++17](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0135r0.html). I know one somewhat hackish way to do it now, but it requires introducing a converting constructor to `StrCatPiece`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a rather hackish way to do this. Aggregate initialization is a copy-initialization context, so the only way to initialize an array element without incurring even a conceptual copy is by copy-list-initialization, i.e., initializing from a `{braced-init-list}`, but this can't use explicit constructors, so we need to give `StrCatPiece` a non-explicit constructor, preferably without creating unwanted implicit conversions.

So, a simple wrapper class template to wrap the actual constructor arguments:

```
template<class U>
struct StrCatPieceArg {
    explicit StrCatPieceArg(U u) : u(u) {}
    U u;
};
```

And a non-`explicit` constructor of `StrCatPiece` that takes a `StrCatPieceArg` and just forwards the wrapped argument to the actual constructor.

```
template<class U>
StrCatPiece(StrCatPieceArg<U> arg) : StrCatPiece(arg.u) {}
```

You don't really lose any explicit-ness here, since the only way to get a `StrCatPieceArg` is by using its explicit constructor.

Another variation on this idea would be to use an extra tag parameter instead of a wrapper class template to mean "yes, I really meant to construct a `StrCatPiece`".

We can now make an array of `StrCatPiece`s, taking care to copy-list-initialize each element so that no temporary is created, even conceptually:

```
template <typename... Types>
std::string StrCat(Types... args) {
    StrCatPiece pieces[] = {{StrCatPieceArg<Types>(args)}...};
                         // ^                           ^  
                         // These braces are important!!!
    //...
}
```